# Sometimes Classes treat like structures in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, arrayobject

for eg:-
In class DishPostedVC, I have an array of model:- 
var finalDatesOfDish : [DishActivationDateTimeModel]?

If i pass this variable (finalDatesOfDish) to class DishActivationVC, and do some deletion operation in class DishActivationVC, and if i go back again to class DishPostedVC, then i am getting data after deletion not the actual data, but i am just coming back not passing any data.

I don't know why but this situation occurred one more time earlier with model array, its so strange, how's it possible?

can u tell me what shld i do?

```
class DishActivationDateTimeModel {

var dayDate: Date? = nil
var dayDateStr: String = ""
var servingsLeft: String = ""
var firstSlotPostedDishId: String = ""
var secondSlotPostedDishId: String = ""

var startTimeDateForFirstSlot: Date? = nil
var startTimeStringForFirstSlot: String = ""
var endTimeDateForFirstSlot: Date? = nil
var endTimeStringForFirstSlot: String = ""

var startTimeDateForSecondSlot: Date? = nil
var startTimeStringForSecondSlot: String = ""
var endTimeDateForSecondSlot: Date? = nil
var endTimeStringForSecondSlot: String = ""
}
```

It's my model

Comment: Classes are reference types and Structures are value types in Swift. You are passing a reference of your object to the next view controller.

Comment: yes Rakesh  but i am using class here, and if i am performing any deletion and going back then its reflecting to its main object but i am not passing data or anything

Comment: so rakesh if i delete any data from the passed reference then come back and want the actual data then what shld i do?

Comment: Create another instance and pass that instance or use struct.

Comment: ok rakesha i will try with Struct then

Comment: @RakeshaShastri according to you what is the good way to work on MODELs?

Comment: use classes or struct?

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you need a value object you use Struct, if you need a reference object you use Class. Most standard library data objects  like String, Array, Dictionary, etc are all structs. I personally haven't found the need to use Struct apart from the predefined ones much.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri  but like i explained here, i need to perform calculations and if user wants to save then he can save otherwise he can go back after deletions but if he didn't save then in this case STRUCT will be better option, what u think/

Comment: Oh... i see your use case now. You are passing an object which the user can modify and choose not to save the changes. If he chooses not to save you have to revert the changes. Use a class and create a copy of it and save the copy to the original if the user chooses to save it. Otherwise just let it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class DishActivationDateTimeModel {

    var dayDate: Date? = nil
    var dayDateStr: String = ""
    var servingsLeft: String = ""
    var firstSlotPostedDishId: String = ""
    var secondSlotPostedDishId: String = ""

    var startTimeDateForFirstSlot: Date? = nil
    var startTimeStringForFirstSlot: String = ""
    var endTimeDateForFirstSlot: Date? = nil
    var endTimeStringForFirstSlot: String = ""

    var startTimeDateForSecondSlot: Date? = nil
    var startTimeStringForSecondSlot: String = ""
    var endTimeDateForSecondSlot: Date? = nil
    var endTimeStringForSecondSlot: String = ""

    init(_ object : DishActivationDateTimeModel) {
        self.dayDate = object.dayDate
        self.dayDateStr = object.dayDateStr
//        ....
//        ....
        self.endTimeStringForSecondSlot = object.endTimeStringForSecondSlot
    }
}
extension Array where Element : DishActivationDateTimeModel {

    func copyModelArray() -> [DishActivationDateTimeModel] {
        var array : [DishActivationDateTimeModel] = []
        for object in self {
            array.append(DishActivationDateTimeModel(object))
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

If you don't want to make changes in your main data then copy your
 model array using `copyModelArray` method. And use your operational
 model array. So, its not affect to your main model data array.

Comment: so u r saying, whenever user delete objects from model-array and he don't SAVE and go back then i need to call this method, is it ?

Comment: Nope, whichever delete operation you are performing.. Perform on operational array which are created using `copyModelArray ` method

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: It's my pleasure bro :)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift structs and classes give you both value and reference-based constructs for your objects. Structs are preferred for objects designed for data storage like Array. Structs also help remove memory issues when passing objects in a multithreaded environment. Classes, unlike structs, support inheritance and are used more for containing logic like UIViewController. Most standard library data objects in Swift, like String, Array, Dictionary, Int, Float, Boolean, are all structs, therefore value objects. The mutability of var versus let is why in Swift there are no mutable and non-mutable versions of collections like Objective C’s NSArray and NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

when you passed around your structs its copied but when you passed or assigned classes it gets reference to it.This means when you change class object in one location it changes everywhere, when you affect structs it changes individually. if you want more information differences between classes and structs you can check araound my article.
[classes versus structs](https://medium.com/dev-genius/class-versus-struct-in-swift-b0ce62bee676)